# onEditingFinished from QML TextInput not getting triggered

Tags: qt, qml, textinput

I have the following `ButtonInputIcon` Item which includes a `TextInput`. However I have not been able to catch the `editingFinished` signal of the `TextInput`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Rectangle {
    width: 86
    height: 48
    property bool buttonActive: true
    property url iconSource: "../images/IC066UpDown.svg"
    property real iconSize: 0.60
    property alias textInputText: textInput.text

    color: buttonActive ? Style.buttonColorOn : Style.buttonColorOff
    radius: 5
    property alias inputMouse: inputMouse
    property alias textInput: textInput

    Rectangle {
        id: borderRect
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 8
        anchors.right: icon.left
        anchors.rightMargin: 8
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 6
        border.color: buttonActive ? Style.buttonColorTextOn : Style.buttonColorTextOff
        color: parent.color
        border.width: 1

        TextInput {
            id: textInput
            color: buttonActive ? Style.buttonColorTextOn : Style.buttonColorTextOff
            text: "10"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 5
            inputMask: "999"
            maximumLength: 3
            selectionColor: "green"
            font.family: stdFont.name
            font.pixelSize: 20
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: inputMouse
            anchors.fill: borderRect
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: icon
        sourceSize.height: parent.height * iconSize
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        source: iconSource
        antialiasing: false
        visible: false
    }

    ColorOverlay {
        color: buttonActive ? Style.buttonColorTextOn : Style.buttonColorTextOff
        anchors.fill: icon
        source: icon
    }
}
```

I'm trying to catch the editingFinished signal here in its .qml file.

```
ButtonInputIconForm {

    textInput.onFocusChanged: console.info("textinput")
    textInput.onEditingFinished:
    {
        console.info("Editing finished ", textInputText)
    }

    inputMouse.onClicked: {
        textInput.focus = true
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have simplified the code even further and now running it in the simplest application possible. I still cannot see the signal triggered when `onEditingFinished` is supposed to be triggered. Following is the new code.

Code in `ButtonInputIconForm.ui.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Rectangle {
    width: 86
    height: 48
    property bool buttonActive: true
    property real iconSize: 0.60
    property alias textInputText: textInput.text

    color: "green"
    property alias inputMouse: inputMouse
    property alias textInput: textInput

    Rectangle {
        id: borderRect
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 8
        anchors.right: icon.left
        anchors.rightMargin: 8
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 6
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 6
        border.color: "red"
        color: parent.color
        border.width: 1

        TextInput {
            id: textInput
            color: "black"
            text: "10"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 5
            inputMask: "999"
            maximumLength: 3
            selectionColor: "blue"
            font.pixelSize: 20
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: inputMouse
            anchors.fill: borderRect
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: icon
        sourceSize.height: parent.height * iconSize
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        antialiasing: false
        visible: false
    }
}
```

Code in `ButtonInputIcon.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

ButtonInputIconForm
{
    textInput.onActiveFocusChanged:
    {
        if (activeFocus)
        {
            console.info("active focus on textinput")
        }
        else
        {
            console.info("active focus not on textinput")
        }
    }

    textInput.onFocusChanged: console.info("focus on textinput")

    inputMouse.onClicked: {
        textInput.focus = true
    }
}
```

Code in `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property alias buttonIcon: buttonIcon
    ButtonInputIcon{
        id: buttonIcon
        textInput.onEditingFinished:
        {
            console.info("buttonIcon.textInput.onEditingFinished", buttonIcon.textInputText)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I learned that because I have set `inputMask: "999"`, `onEditingFinished` is only triggered when 3 digits number is written before pressing enter. That's the issue.

Comment: Your code is working. The signal is triggered when the user press `Enter` key or when the textInput loses the focus (for example, when the use clicks outside). Do you want to trigger the signal in another case?

Comment: @RomhaKorev Thanks for the reply, but I still haven't managed to see that the singal is triggered when `Enter` is pressed or texinput loses focus. I have added a new edit. Could you please see now what could be the issue?

Comment: Your alias is called `textInputText`, yet in the main.qml you use `textInput`

Comment: @Amfasis `textInputText` is the alias for text in textInput. The alias `textInput` is the `TextInput` object itself. How is that wrong? And `textInputText` doesn't even have `onEditingFinished`.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad! You are correct. Well in that case it might have to do with `FocusScope`s, can you try adding another text input inside `uttonInputIconForm.ui.qml` and see if switching towards that one triggers?

Comment: @Amfasis Thanks about the suggestion. Yes, now after adding another similar `TextInput` inside `ButtonInputIconForm.ui.qml` onEditingFinished does get triggered. Why is it so? I don't need to the other `TextIput`. What do you think I should do to not have to use it?

Comment: I think you might be able to get around by following this [Qt Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html). But I do find it a bit of a hassle...

Comment: @Amfasis I think I have found the solution. I'm updating my question and then you can seem what I meant.

Comment: I would say that is an answer, not an edit ;-) and yes, you can post an answer to your own question